# how to use mylvmbackup

Tags: mysql, backup, database, mysql-replication

any useful tips or easiest way

Comment: Seriously... documentation exists for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by taking a look at [their own site](http://www.lenzg.net/mylvmbackup/) (i guess).
Especially the [Documentation and Links](http://www.lenzg.net/mylvmbackup/#Docs) section.

Also: please wait at least for an answer on one site before cross posting it to another:

> https://superuser.com/questions/52137/how-to-use-mylvmbackup

Answer (score 1):

How about consulting the [Documentation](http://www.lenzg.net/mylvmbackup/#Docs) first and then come back with a more specific question?